# why is reference to outer object always needed for non-final non-private inner classes

Tags: scala

While reading [SI-1419](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1419), I was wondering why inner classes always need a pointer to their surrounding class when they're not final/private.

In general, this is needed for matching of inner objects, but somehow the compiler doesn't care too much about this and doesn't allow this for `final` classes:

```
class A { class B }
val a = new A
val a2 = new A
val b = new a2.B
(b: Any) match {
  case _: a.B => 1
  case _: a2.B => 2
}
===> 2
```

but change the class to final:

```
class A { final class B }
val a = new A
val a2 = new A
val b = new a2.B
(b: Any) match {
  case _: a.B => 1
  case _: a2.B => 2
}
<console>:17: warning: The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
             case _: a.B => 1
                   ^
<console>:18: warning: The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
             case _: a2.B => 2
                   ^

===> 1
```

So the result of this test depends on the `final` word here. From my understanding of [2](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1419?focusedCommentId=72666&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-72666), this is not the only reason for the outer field, but this field seems to be necessary for constructors of classes extending this inner class. I don't really understand the reasoning here. Maybe you could help me with an example:

> When the nested class is final, you can reason locally about whether
>   the outer accessor is needed (except for the pattern matching type
>   test, which is weakened in the absence of the outer field). **If the
>   class is not final, a subclass (potentially defined in a separate
>   compilation unit/run) may cause an outer accessor to be needed.** See
>   https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/Constructors.scala#L113-L116

Comment: Possibly related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/vw8Kek4zlZ8/LAeakfeR3RoJ